# Rackspace/Vagrant: Working with a rackspace vagrant box locally

Tags: vagrant, rackspace-cloud

I was reading through Rackspace's [article about using Vagrant with Rackspace open cloud](http://developer.rackspace.com/blog/vagrant-now-supports-rackspace-open-cloud.html) which shows you how you can use a vagrant vm that is hosted on a Rackspace server.

I'm wondering if there's any way that I could work from a vm that is provisioned like a Rackspace server on my **local** machine via Vagrant. I can't seem to find a box specifically for emulating Rackspace servers and I can't find information on what base OS and basic tools rackspace cloud servers actually use so I could provision my own environment.

Is there a place where I can find a rackspace specific vagrant box or at least find out the os info?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit:
Correction, it is possible, but it takes a few steps:

1. Export (from Rackspace) the image that you want to run locally [see here for more info](http://docs.rackspace.com/images/api/v2/ci-devguide/content/POST_exportImage_tasks_Image_Task_Calls.html)
2. Download image from Cloud Files
3. Convert/import the vhd file into VirtualBox [see this for example](http://www.macrium.com/help/v5/How_to/ImgToVHD/Create_a_virtual_machine_using_ImgToVHD.htm)
4. At this point, you should be able to use that image with Vagrant to run a Rackspace image locally.